# KnockoutJS observing object of observables

Tags: knockout.js

I am building a set of filters in Knockout and want to store the current filter settings on an object. When any is changed, I need to filter my data.

The subscription to `self.filter` is never triggered, even though the Filter object changes. Can this be observed?

```js
var Filter = function() {
    this.gender = ko.observable("");
    this.role = ko.observable("");
};
viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable(new Filter());
  self.filter.subscribe(function(obj) {
    console.log("The filter has been modified! (this line never runs)", obj);
  });
  
  self.output = function() { console.log("Gender", self.filter().gender(), "Role", self.filter().role());}
};

vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<select data-bind="value: filter().gender">
  <option value="">Male or Female</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
<select data-bind="value: filter().role">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
</select>

<p>
<button data-bind="click: output">
Output Filter values (to prove the object is updated)
</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` does not change, which is why the subscription function doesn't get hit.  The `gender` and `role` observables of the `filter` *do* change, however.

`self.filter().gender.subscribe()` will get called when the gender dropdown changes.  The only way `self.filter.subscribe()` will get called is if you change the value of the filter itself, for example `self.filter(new Filter())`.

There is not much point to making `filter` observable if all it is going to have is observable properties (unless you are going to create new filters like in the example above instead of just changing its properties).

Comment: Be careful about creating lots of subscriptions though (they hang around and _will_ use memory - a SPA can be impacted heavily over time) - in theory you'd need to subscribe when `filter` _does_ change - at that point you should probably also dispose the subscriptions from the previous `filter` value.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Oh! I was looking for a memory leak earlier, will check the other subscriptions.

Comment: @PeterB If your page lives for any non-trivial length of time, it's pretty important to ensure that the return value from every `subscribe` is stored somewhere and a corresponding call to [`dispose`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#highlighter_397069) is used at the right time.

Comment: @Paul Abbott Thanks, that makes more sense. What is a better way to architect this code - should I keep observables on `Filter` (necessary to bind to the HTML I believe), or move everything potentially to the viewModel? As there will be another 10+ filters I'm looking for a clean way to address them all and apply all which are set to the data.